# How to configure SSMTP to use the hostname from the host instead of hardcoding it in ssmtp.conf?

Tags: ssmtp

I want to deploy the ssmtp config to multiple machines and not have to hardcode the hostname to `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain your situation a bit better? In most enviroments, all systems should have the same relay name to drop mails to, because that's what SSMTP is designed to to.

Comment: It is about the `hostname=` parameter from the config file, which says how to present the machine name sending the email, it is not the SMTP server. I tried to comment it and the messages are still sent but SSMTP does not add the machine hostname to the messages.

Comment: Sorry, but where do you want ssmtp to add the machine hostname to the messages? If you don't specify the `hostname` parameter, ssmtp will use the configured hostname (i.e. the name you get when you enter the `hostname` command).